# Is there any point in testing a for-in loop?

Tags: javascript, testing

to verify the language ( ES5 ) is behaving functionally the same across browsers?

Or are language implementations for control structures so robust that it is not needed?
Here is one example test.

```
var test_set = [null, undefined, NaN, true, false, 1, 'a',{test:'test'},[0], function(){}, /test/];

var index, 
    key;

for(index = 0; index < test_set.length; index++){
    console.log('Mark | ' + test_set[index]);
    for (key in test_set[index]) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should view it as testing your logic, and not the implementation.  Yes, it may seem silly to test a `for-loop`, but it's not silly to test that say, something is appended the correct number of times.  What if you have an off-by-one error?  What if the logic changes in the future altogether? Tests are meant as "proofs" that the code behaves as expected, not that the coding framework is working.

So if your function/logic is covered, and you simply want to test if it's consistent across browsers, then I'd say go ahead and test that functionality, because again, in the future it may change, or you may just have an error you missed.  On the other hand if you're testing the Javascript framework *itself* (ie ensuring a `for loop` iterates over elements in a list), then you can bypass writing tests for that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not be testing that a for loop behaves as expected. Test the code you've written, not the language on which its running.

The entire concept is fundamentally flawed: You realize your tests are written in JavaScript? If you don't trust the JavaScript implementation, how can you possibly trust the validity of your tests?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are the one writing the implementation of the for loop for that language, there's no point in testing the construct. Test the code that you write, and assume that the language behaves as designed.

Of course, languages don't always behave as designed, and if you notice a defect you should report it, but if you spend all your time testing the underlying language instead of your own code, you're wasting a lot of your time.